# Invalid Outside Procedure when defining DLL function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet Lib "C:\Program Files\EPLAN\EEC One\2.7.3\Platform64\W3ApiBase.dll" Alias "EecOne.GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet" () As Integer

Call Application.Run("EecOne.GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet")

End Function

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet

End Sub
```

I'm trying to call a function within the .dll file and I get the error 'Invalid outside procedure'.

This is the only piece of documentation available for the dll/API I'm trying to use:

[image: Attached image]

and this:

[image: Attached image]

Comment: `Call ...` is an executable statement, not a declaration. *That's* what's illegal outside a procedure scope. `End Function` also seems out of place.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks, I fixed that portion according to the answer below, but I'm still not sure how to use the Application.Run portion of the code as specified in the API documentation.

Comment: You don't need `Application.Run` (which itself doesn't need a `Call` keyword) - below answer demonstrates that the only thing you need to invoke the imported function, is its name... like you have it.

Comment: Ohk, thanks for clearing the doubt. I'll keep digging why I'm getting the 'can't find entry point error.

Comment: Is the library correctly registered? If it's written in .NET, it needs to be registered for COM interop. If there's a .tlb file with the same name as the .dll, try referencing that instead.

Comment: I don't see any .tlb files. I tried regasm, didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Syntax should be like this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet Lib "C:\Program Files\EPLAN\EEC One\2.7.3\Platform64\W3ApiBase.dll" Alias "EecOne.GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet" () As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet
End Sub
```

Note that `Private Declare PtrSafe Function` is just like a reference to a function in a library. It's just to make it available and has no source code and no `End Function`. It's more like a link to a function.

---

Issue here was that these two lines …

```
Call Application.Run("EecOne.GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet")
End Function
```

were not within a function or procedure therefore you got the error …

> Invalid outside procedure

Comment: When I try this, it says 'Can't find the entry point to EecOne.GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet' in the .dll file. So I don't have to use the `Call Application.Run` portion of the code as specified in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: That error means that it cannot find a function named `EecOne.GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet` in the .dll. Are you sure your `Declare` statement is correct? Hard to tell whats wrong here since I don't know anything about that dll.

Comment: @Inception could it be that you don't need that `Declare` statement at all, only add the `EecOne` type library as a reference to your project, and then you can invoke the function as you would any VBA or Excel function?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried referencing all 4 dll files available and I get the same error for all. So I think it's something else.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That is a possibility, but I tried adding the dll file as reference but it said 'Can't add reference to the specified file' which is why I tried declaring them

Comment: Since your documentation tells you to use `Call Application.Run("EecOne.GenerateActiveTypicalWorksheet")` I assume that there is something like a Excel AddIn that provides the access to your dll? Are there any AddIn files provided? So you don't need to declare the dll but load an AddIn or something? We can only guess here because we don't have the documentation. Probably they provide information there how to use it?